# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject in Asynctask

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

I am trying to Parse JSON Data get From URL and Insert Data to Firebase from response using `asynctask`.Below is the code I have written but it is not inserting any data to Firebase.My Firebase Reference is correct as I log.e Below is the code

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(context.getResources().getText(R.string.bid_request).toString().trim()).child("b");

for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
  Map<String, Object> userValues = new HashMap<>();

  final String node = obj.getString("mysql_id");
  final String id = obj.getString("id");

  DatabaseReference newBid = mDatabase.child(node);

     String data = obj.getString("new_comer");
     String[] items = data.split(",");
     for (String item : items) {
                userValues.put(item, 1);
     }

     serValues.put("tReq", obj.getString("tReq"));

     newBid.setValue(userValues, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                   if(databaseError!=null){
                       Log.e("error", "onComplete: "+databaseError);
                   }
                }
      });
```

And below is the Error showing in my log.Can not figure out what is wrong I am doing

> E/myapp: onPostExecute: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"14248","mysql_id":"a6555018-de41-4fc7-942e-530389aa3a9d","tReq":"4","new_comer":"10019,10029"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What line is giving this error? Note that we'll likely need to know what `result` is to be able to help. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read it carefully please, as it contains a lot of useful information on maximizing the chances that someone can help).

Comment: it is not giving error but data is not saving to firebase. in log i got this error

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the code to do instead? Please edit the question to be specific about what you're trying to achieve, and the specific data you're working with.